# Why are the web links in my scheduled email broken?

Tags: civimail, civimember, email, error, links

When I send a test email via CRM, the web links work perfectly. When the actual email is shared, it arrives in the recipient's inbox with none of the web links working.

Could you

Comment: CMS you are using?

Comment: This is going to be hard to answer without some examples.  What is the URL that works, and what is the URL that's generated when the actual email goes out?